# live search ajax multiple input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have multiple inputs but it dont search if i run it. what did i have to do to fix my issue

```
$(document).ready(function()
load_data();
    function load_data()
    {
        $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        var second=str3;
        $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{search:search, second:second},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: use a class instead of ID to call `.keyup()`. Just make sure that each input has a different ID but share the same class name

Comment: Like @Rotimi said, an ID must be unique on a page if you have multiple inputs with the same ID, the query selector ($('#search_test') will only find the first element with the ID. Use a CSS class to get all elements and in the one of the best practice is to prefix the CSS class with 'js-' to make the difference between a CSS class for the styles and the CSS class as JS selector.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, make sure that each input has the same class name but different ID attribute values. Then call `.keyup()` using the class name

```
<input id='search1' class='search_input' />
<input id='search2' class='search_input' />
<input id='search3' class='search_input' />
```

Then call as:

```
$('.search_input').keyup(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rotimi recommended you have to use `class` instead of an `id`

> data:{search:search, second:second},

If you want to compute an object with multiple input values you can use following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  load_data();

})

function load_data() {
  $('.search_text').keyup(function() {
    var data = $('.search_text').map((index, element) => ({
      name: $(element).attr("name"),
      value: $(element).val()
    })).get().reduce(function(acc, {
      name,
      value
    }) {
      acc[name] = value;
      return acc;
    }, {})
    
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="search_text" name="search" type="text" />
<input class="search_text" name="second" type="text" />
```

Also don't forget to use `debounce` as you can exhaust your backend with so many requests